# Count <tr> HTML tag grouped by their @class attribute name in XPath

Tags: html, xpath

I need a XPath expression that count all the `<tr>` rows that have a  starting class attribute string: `room_loop_counter` grouped by their attribute name itself.
I have the following sample HTML code to extract data from:

```
<tbody id="container" >
   <tr class="room_loop_counter1 maintr">
      <td class="legibility " rowspan="6"></td>
      <td colspan="4" style="padding:0;"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter1">
      <td ></td>
      <td class=""></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter1"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter2 maintr divider"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter2"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter3 maintr divider"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter3"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter3"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter3"></tr>
   <tr class="room_loop_counter3"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Given the above HTML I would want to get as result : **2,1,4**. *The count is the number of elements minus one, since I want to discard from the count the first `<tr>`(the one with the `maintr`) that is the header...*

Between `<tr>` elements there could be other `<tr>` elements so their are not strictly one after the other, so we can't rely on following or preceding sibling logic.

I've tried with the following XPath expression :

```
count(//table[@id="maxotel_rooms"]/tbody/tr[@class=distinct-values(//table[@id="maxotel_rooms"]/tbody/tr[starts-with(@class, "room_loop_counter") and not(contains(@class, "maintr"))]/@class)]/@class])
```

but it doesn't work on chrome(evaluating it with `$x('')` on the console window) since it doesn't recognize the `distinct-values` function.
Could you suggest a possible solution? What is the best approach ?

Comment: This might return required number of nodes `count(//tr[starts-with(@class, substring-before(//tr[contains(@class, "maintr")]/@class, " maintr")) and not(contains(@class, "maintr"))])`, but AFAIK `count()` returns only the first occurence (in your case only `2`), but not all occurences (`2`, `1`, `4`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this XPath for unique tr with class starts with some data and not followed by some other class name.

> //tbody/tr[starts-with(@class, "room_loop_counter") and not(contains(@class, "maintr"))]/following::tr[not(./@class=following::tr/@class) and not(contains(@class, "maintr"))]

Javascript:

```
var path = "//body/div";
var uniquePathCount = window.document.evaluate('count(' + path + ')', window.document, null, 0, null);
console.log( uniquePathCount );
console.log( uniquePathCount.numberValue );
```

Ouput:

```
<tr class="room_loop_counter1"/>
<tr class="room_loop_counter2"/>
<tr class="room_loop_counter3"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've well explained... Between `<tr>` elements there could be other `<tr>` elements so their are not strictly one after the other, so we can't rely on following or preceding sibling logic. In addition your output is not my desired output since I want to get the count of elements having the same class...

Comment: Try [this url](https://www.booking.com/hotel/it/appartamenti-spiaggia-longa.it.html?checkin=2017-11-25;checkout=2017-11-26). Basically I want to extract the number of rows inside the two main rows ... If you look at the page source you will find `room_loop_counter` class ...